# <div> and <select> tags

Tags: html, html-select

Can I have a `<DIV>` within an HTML `<SELECT>` tag?

e.g.:

```
<select tabindex="2" name="agegrp" id="agegrp" >
    <div> 
        <option value="-1">No preference</option>
    </div>
</select>
```

Comment: as far as i understand, you can only have "option" elements within a "select" element.

Comment: Why do you want to use like that ?

Comment: i am using ajax.So i was thinking of changing the option withing the select.This i was trying to do with javascrip by replacing div

Comment: I was recently tempted to put DIV inside SELECT myself, but I think for a different reason. Here was *my* motivation: I liked how SELECT takes care of arranging things in a vertical list and takes care of the clicking/highlighting behavior for you and ensures that only one thing is selected at a time. I still wanted all that. But I also wanted each list item to be an elaborate box of my own design (e.g. showing multiple field names/value pairs plus a small photo), rather than a single text string. Those two requirements would be trivial to combine if you could use DIVs inside SELECT/OPTION.

Comment: I'm also trying to do similiar thing. Looking comments, I see I won't use div inside select. Maybe I can create a table of divs inside a div having vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6):

```
<!ELEMENT SELECT - - (OPTGROUP|OPTION)+ -- option selector -->
```

i.e. There is an element called "SELECT", the start tag is required, the end tag is required. It's children can be OPTGROUP elements and/or OPTION elements and there must be at least one of them.

Since a DIV is not an OPTGROUP or an OPTION, the answer is **no**.

Answer (score 4):

No. Nope. Niet.

Answer (score 0):

No.  And there is no reason to.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you may be interested in the `optgroup` element. Be aware that its appearance tends to vary a lot across different browsers before you start building designs around it though.

Answer (score 0):

While you can generate any crazy HTML you want, that is not a recommended use of DIV. **What is the problem you are trying to solve** by introducing the DIV?

Perhaps you are unaware of the [OPTGROUP](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) tag?

> The  tag is used to group
>   together related options in a select
>   list.
>
> If you have a long list of options,
>   groups of related options are easier
>   to handle for the user.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has stated there would be no need to do a div within a select list.  if you need to individually move list elements in a form id suggest using radio buttons.