# How to get the selected option in an html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to retrieve the `id` of my option that I selected. Over here you can see my HTML.

```
<select name="zaal" id="zaal">
    <DIV CONTENTEDITABLE="FALSE" ID="MACONTAINER" MACONSTRAINT="" MAPARAMETER="ZALEN">
        <DIV CONTENTEDITABLE="TRUE" ID="MAITEM">
            <option value="~@ITEM.ID~" id="ZAALNAME">~ITEM.ID~, ~ITEM.NAME~</option>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
</select>
```

I am doing it like this.

```
var selectVal = $("#zaal :selected").val();
var id = selectVal.substring(1);
console.log("id is: " + selectVal);
```

But for some reason it won't work.

Can anybody help?

**EDIT**

Ok the divs are the problem. But I need those to get my values from my database.So I think I need to find another solution than a select.

Comment: `select` element should contain either `option` or `optgroup` elements only.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that a `div` is ***not*** a valid child of a `select` element; the reason your jQuery isn't working (apart from any other problems) is that you have invalid HTML and the browser's trying to 'rescue' it by correcting the DOM in some manner.

Comment: @ All the answers: You cannot select ANY element inside this `<select> `, because it is NOT valid HTML!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#zaal option:selected").attr('value'); // will return you ~@ITEM.ID~
```

To get the `id`

```
$("#zaal option:selected").attr('id'); // will return you ZAALNAME
```

To get `id` on selection change try this:

```
$('#zaal').on('change', function() {

  // To get id
  $('option:selected', this).attr('id');

  $('option:selected', this).attr('value'); // return the value of selected option

  // To get the select box value
  var value = this.value;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
$("#zaal option:selected").val();
```

Also, try moving the divs outside of the select element.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question:

[<div> and <select> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499216/html-div-and-select-tag)

You can only put `<option>` or `<optgroup>` inside a `<select>`. If you want to put anything else in there you have to make some kind of list yourself.

Why would you like to put any div inside a select anyway?

---

If I put the HTML you gave me (with edited strings) inside Google Chome, this is what is made of your code:

```
<select name="zaal" id="zaal">
  <option value="x" id="ZAALNAME">X, Y</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#zaal option[value='0']").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectVal = $("#zaal option:selected").val();
var id = selectVal.substring(1);
console.log("id is: " + selectVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The html should be

```
<select name="zaal" id="zaal">
  <option value="~@ITEM.ID~" id="ZAALNAME">~ITEM.ID~, ~ITEM.NAME~</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#zaal').change(function(){
    alert($($(this)+':selected').attr('id'));

});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cBaZ7/1/

Comment: If you bind the event other than .change() you do: `$('#zaal option:selected').attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

`val()` will retrieve the value of the selected option. It is not the `id`

So try this:

```
 $("#zaal option:selected").attr("id")
```