# Hiding/showing the select box options in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

i have below code snippet in jsp

```
<HTML>
 <BODY>
     <select id="customerIds" onchange="doOperation()">
                <option value="default"> Start..</option>
                  <div id="action1" class="action1">
                    <option value="1"> 1</option>
                    <option value="2"> 2</option>
                    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                  </div>
                  <div id="action2" class="action2">
                    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                  </div>
                  <option value="5"> 5 </option>
              </select>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

on click of certain button, i want to hide the options with id  as "action1" and display the options with Id as "action2". So i tried this

```
  $('#action1').hide();
  $('#action2').show();
```

But that did not work.Not getting whats the issue? In firebug when i tried to inspect the select box, i did not find any div tag(i.e
 with ids  action1/action2 )  above options.

Comment: You cannot write `div` tag inside `select` and `option` tag.

Comment: You may want to pursue using the span tab instead as that tag is inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below javascript function where showOptionsClass is the class given to each option you want to show. This will
work in cross browser.

```
function showHideSelectOptions(showOptionsClass) {
    var optionsSelect = $('#selectId');
    optionsSelect.find('option').map(function() {
        return $(this).parent('span').length == 0 ? this : null;
    }).wrap('<span>').attr('selected', false).hide();

    optionsSelect.find('option.' + showOptionsClass).unwrap().show()
        .first().attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
```

Comment: @M Sach: I tried to apply your solution to my issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381003/jquery-and-css-hide-show-select-options-with-a-certain-css-class). It doesn't work on IE 10 and Chrome, meanwhile on Firefox it works only if I refresh the page and I can see all the options at the first time. I would to have the only "Choose..." option and, when the user chooses a value from the first select, display only the corresponding options and the "Choose..." option selected

Answer (score 2):

You may not have `<div>` elements within a `<select>`, see for example [this stackoverflow on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499216/div-and-select-tags), which references [this bit](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) of the HTML spec.

Further, hiding options isn't cross browser compatible (see [this stackoverflow (second answer))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery), as @Voitek Zylinski suggests, you would probably be better off keeping multiple copies of the select and toggling between them, or if keeping the `id` attribute is required then maybe even adjusting the innerHtml (yuck...).

You could maybe approach it like:

**markup**

```
<select onchange="doOperation()" class="js-opt-a">
        <option value="default"> Start..</option>
            <option value="1"> 1</option>
            <option value="2"> 2</option>
            <option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>
<select onchange="doOperation()" class="js-opt-b">
    <option value="default">Start...</option>
    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
    <option value="5"> 5 </option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
function doOperation() { /*whatever*/}
$(".js-opt-a").hide();
$(".js-opt-b").show();​​
```

See for example [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSs6w/)

Not exactly ideal though!

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `div` to group but you can assign `class` to `options` to group them.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/TmYdn/)**

```
<select id="customerIds" onchange="doOperation()">
      <option value="default"> Start..</option>              
      <option value="1" class="action1"> 1</option>
      <option value="2" class="action1"> 2</option>
      <option value="3" class="action1"> 3 </option>
      <option value="4" class="action2"> 4 </option>
      <option value="5" class="action3"> 5 </option>
</select>​

$('.action1').hide();
$('.action2').show();​
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be hiding them on my machine (os x/chrome 23)?

Comment: huh, hiding options isn't cross browser ([learn something new everyday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery))

Comment: @ Kieran That seems true. It worked on Firefox but not on IE 8

Answer (score 0):

You can't group  options inside a div. You can group them inside an <**optgroup**>, but I don't think that's what you're aiming for.

What you should do instead, is to either create two dropdowns that you toggle between or keep one dropdown and repopulate its options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $('.action1').wrap('<span></span>').hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
     $('.action1').unwrap('<span></span>').show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="customerIds" onchange="doOperation()">
          <option value="default"> Start..</option>              
          <option value="1" class="action1"> 1</option>
          <option value="2" class="action1"> 2</option>
          <option value="3" class="action1"> 3 </option>
          <option value="4" class="action2"> 4 </option>
          <option value="5" class="action3"> 5 </option>
    </select>​
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
</body>
</html>
```