# Struts 1.3 and IE: property value isn't displayed on error and by using back button

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, properties, struts-1

I've a form which contains three related selections (properties are zeroselect, firstselect, secondselect).
When the user chooses a value from the firstselect, the second select is populated like it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381003/jquery-and-css-hide-show-select-options-with-a-certain-css-class) and in the corresponding answer.

The issue is that when the form is submitted and there is an error or when the form is submitted, another page is displayed and the user clicks on the back button, IE doesn't display the user chosen value for the second select (Firefox and Chrome do).

All the other properties are set properly.

**EDIT**

In case of error, I resolved via jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved via jquery by setting an hidden field value if the browser is IE.

Then the first thing I do in $(function(){}); is set a var with the value of the hidden field if browser is IE else with the value of the property for the select.