# How to keep visible only the option on select in a dropdown menu

Tags: html, html-select

How to keep only the select option remain visible in a dropdown menu.

```
<select name="month" id="my_month">
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03" selected="selected">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">Jun</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">Septembar</option>
<option value="10">Octobor</option><option value="11">Novembar</option>
<option value="12">Decembar</option>    
 </select>
```

From the dropdown, I wish to keep only 'select' part visible. Possible with CSS?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to see "Month" rather than a dropdown with "March" pre-selected in this example? http://jsfiddle.net/4nYPa/

Comment: Yes, in the drop-down, I want to see only the month selected.. in this case it's march. If if place `#my_month { display: none;}`, the entire box disappears. But I wish to make the select March visible, does not matter if the entire drop-down functionality goes away

Answer (score 1):

$("#my_month option").hide();

$("#my_month > option[selected==selected]").show();

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible with CSS, but my stab at it doesn't quite work in Chrome and not nearly in IE.

```
#my_month option { display: none;}
#my_month option[selected="selected"] { display: inline;}
```

This is a candidate for jQuery and there are at least a couple question that show some methods.

[jquery-and-css-hide-show-select-options-with-a-certain-css-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381003/jquery-and-css-hide-show-select-options-with-a-certain-css-class)

[how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)

Comment: Thanks Karl. Yeap it's working, even in Chrome, but sadly not in IE. I just tested it. It's working on almost all popular browsers but not on IE.