# PHP variable stores different values?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am clueless with this problem. I have a variable called `$opts`. I use it to fill a select with results from a database query (mysql).

```
<select id="User" name="User" >
<?php 
  $cons=array();
  $opts=getOptions("User",$cons,0);
  logge(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$TAG." - ".$fn." - opts are=".$opts);
  echo $opts;?>
</select>
```

This is working and the select is filled with usernames:

```
<option value="1">admin</option>
<option value="2">test</option>
```

I have to select-multiples to be filled depending on the username that is  selected.
Here is the Javascript in the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    //  rootloc returns root url
    var $_GET = {},
    args = location.href.substr(0).split("/");
    var rootloc="http://"+args[2]+"/"+args[3]+"/";     

$("select").change(function() {
    console.log("select on change called.");
    var elem=this.id;     //this.id  id of the calling element
    console.log("Element= " + elem);
    var seluserid=$(this).val(); // returns userid of selected user
    console.log(seluserid);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",rootloc+"DokumenteUserForm.php?seluserid="+seluserid,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
});
//after first load fire change event to fill lists      
console.log("call the onchange first")
obj = document.getElementById("User");
fireEvent(obj,'change');
```

});

Now i am filling two lists regarding the selected user with values form the database: (back to html and php)

```
<select id="Dokumente" name="Dokumente" multiple="multiple" size="10">
<?php 
   if (isset($_GET["seluserid"])){
     $seluserid=$_GET["seluserid"];
     logge(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$TAG." - ".$fn." - seluserid= ". $seluserid);
     $opts2=getListOptions("Dokumente",$seluserid,0);
     logge(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$TAG." - ".$fn." - opts are=".$opts2);
     echo $opts2;}
?>
</select>
```

The second list is filled the same way.

```
<select id="UserDoumente" name="Userdokumente" multiple="multiple" size="10">
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["seluserid"])){
  $opts3="";
  $opts3=(string)$opts3;
  $seluserid=$_GET["seluserid"];
  logge(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$TAG." - ".$fn." - seluserid= ".$seluserid);
  $opts3=getListOptions("Userdokumente",$seluserid,0);
  logge(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$TAG." - ".$fn." - opts3 are= ".$opts3);
  $opts=$opts3;
}
logge(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$TAG." - ".$fn." - opts are=".$opts);
echo $opts;
?>
```

My Problem is right in the last select-multiple list. I am logging the built html code in different places. First in the called `funciton getListOptions`. The Result there is:

```
2015-06-18 17:45:22 - table.php - getListOptions - opts are=<option value="1">Doks/uploads/</option>
```

Now i am logging , as you can see above, right after this is saved in `$opts3`:

```
2015-06-18 17:45:22 - DoksForm.php - mainhtml - opts3 are=<option value="1">Doks/uploads/</option>
```

Then i am putting the `$opts3` into `$opts` an log says:

```
2015-06-18 17:45:22 - DoksForm.php - mainhtml - opts are=<option value="1">Doks/uploads/</option>
```

But when echoing those $opts the values of the first selects appear in the box (HTML source code):

```
<select id="UserDokumente" name="Userdokumente" multiple="multiple" size="10">
  <option value="1">admin</option>
  <option value="2">test</option>
</select>
```

How can this be? As I understand it, i am overwriting this $opts with new values. An so does my log say... Do you have an idea? I dont know how to describe the problem or what words are good to google for this problem. So i tried to explain it here. If there is further information needed, i hopefully can provide it.

If I use `echo $opts3;` instead, nothing is in the list nor in the html source code so it seems like an empty variable. Then I get a PHP Error saying `$opts3` is undefined.
Can it be that the variables inside the isset if statement are others than outside? Or can it be that maybe my xampp installation is broken?(but everything else seems to  work) -> reinstalled xampp -> problem is still there

The problem lies in the xmlhttp request part. I tried it with ajax this request instead (replaced the xmlhttp stuff with that):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'DokumenteUserForm.php?seluserid='+seluserid,
// data: $('form').serialize(),
success: function () {
  //alert('form was submitted');
}
});
```

I logged the url before php builds the html code for the options and it says:

```
2015-06-19 16:35:28 - DokumenteUserForm.php - mainhtml - absolute_url= http://localhost/testwebsite/DokumenteUserForm.php?seluserid=2
```

So as excpected. The thing is, in the browser itself the url didn't change. It is still `http://localhost/testwebsite/DokumenteUserForm.php` as before. 
So I think the url has only changed on server side, not on client side. Maybe thats the same with my `$opts3`variable?

Comment: `$opts3 = ""; $opts3 = (string)$opts3`? **WHY**? You've already created an empty string. casting a string to a string is utterly pointless... and you're using jquery. WHY are you doing a manual xmlhttprequest? why not just use $.ajax() and save yourself a few dozen lines of code?

Comment: the $opts3 = ""; $opts3 = (string)$opts3 was just trying things out to get this, thought of a conversion problem...
i am just beginng web development this was a way i found to get the javascript variable for handling in php

Comment: you may have a problem with the generated html, the logged value is `<option> value="1">`, it should be `<option value="1">`

Comment: unfortunately that is not the problem, i just checked the log again, it's simply a typo. I'll correct this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, and i think i know the reason it didn't work before.
If this was the problem, it's a simple answer and it took me more than 3 days to find it.

My problem was, that i was trying to populate a html select (multiple) by only replacing the options inside the select. I didnt had a div in there but trying it with divs brought me to this thread: [<div> and <select> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499216/div-and-select-tags)

With the detour over div i came to the solution to set the elements inner html.

So now i have an empty select element first:

```
<select id="Dokumente" name="Dokumente" multiple="multiple" size="10">

</select>
```

then in my onchange javascript function i do an ajax post and set the inner html with the result:

```
var url="getMselectopts.php";
var p1 = $.post(url,{what:"Dokumente",u:seluserid});
p1.done(function(data){
// console.log(data);
document.getElementById("Dokumente").innerHTML = data;
});
```

And finally it works.